# Python class decorator that overrides internal method

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, overriding, decorator

I'm trying to write a decorator that can be used to override a method during inheritance, but externally.
Something like:

```
class A:
   def some_method(self):
       print('does stuff')

def override(method):
    # override decorator
    ....

def some_method_override():
    print('does other stuff')

@override(method, some_method_override)
class B:
    #overridden

a = A()
b = B()
a.some_method() # prints 'does stuff'
b.some_method() # prints 'does other stuff'
```

If anyone could share some ideas on this, that would be great!

Comment: Why? This seems like a pretty weird thing to do, with no real benefit and a few weird caveats (like breaking single-argument `super`).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica potentially having many classes inherit from A and overriding a specific method in the same way, but changing others - so you could reuse methods

Comment: I would look into the mock library if you are trying to dynamically override methods. Here is a resource - https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Comment: (whoops, meant breaking 0-argument super in my earlier comment - single-argument super is a weird historical artifact that is almost never useful for anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would go about solving the issue based on use-case;

1. FOR TESTS - I would look into the mock library if you are trying to dynamically override methods. Here is a resource - https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html
2. FOR SEPARATE CLASS - If it is class-wide change I would go with a child class that overrides the original method; this will make your code much more explicit

   ```
   class A:
       def some_method(self):
           print('do_stuff_a')

   class B(A):
       def some_method(self):
           print('do_stuff_b')

   a = A()
   a.some_method() # print 'do_stuff_a'
   b = B()
   a.some_method() # prints 'do_stuff_b'
   ```
3. FOR SPECIFIC SITUATION - If you only want this behavior to occur sometimes, I would use the state-observer code pattern - here is an example

   ```
   class A:
       def __init__(self)
           self._use_method_a = True

       def use_method_a(self, use_method_a):
           self._use_method_a = use_method_a

       def some_method(self):
           if self._use_method_a:
               return self._method_a()
           else:
               return self._method_b()

       def _method_a(self):
           print('do_stuff_a')

       def _method_b(self):
           print('do_other_stuff_b')

   a = A()
   a.some_method() # print 'do_stuff_a'
   a.use_method_a(False) 
   a.some_method() # prints 'do_other_stuff_b'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others in the comments, I don't see any need for a decorator here. It's just a matter of class-attribute assignment.

Inheritance doesn't happen when a class is defined; methods from the parent aren't "pulled in" to the child class. Rather, it happens during attribute lookup. If `B.some_method` isn't defined, then the value of `A.some_method` is used. So to override a parent-class method, you simply provide a definition of the desired class attribute. Methods are just class attributes with values of type `function`.

```
class A:
   def some_method(self):
       print('does stuff')


def some_method_override(self):
    print('does other stuff')


class B(A):
    some_method = some_method_override

a = A()
b = B()
a.some_method() # prints 'does stuff'
b.some_method() # prints 'does other stuff'
```

If you did want a decorator, it would simply be something like

```
def override(old: str, new: Callable):
    def _(cls):
        setattr(cls, old, new)
        return cls
    return _


def some_method_override(self):
    print('does other stuff')


class A:
   def some_method(self):
       print('does stuff')


@override('some_method', some_method_override)
class B(A):
    pass
```